# ActivatedRoute & AuthGuard - issue getting ID from paramMap

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently developing a website for an exam project, however I'm running into the issue of my code not returning the proper ID when I'm using my AuthGuard.

event-details.component.ts

```
  getEvent(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.eventService.getEvent(id)
      .subscribe(event => this.event = event);
      console.log(id);
  }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
  {path: 'events', component: EventsComponent},
  {path: 'events/4', component: EventDetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailsComponent},
```

admin.guard.ts

```
 canActivate(): boolean {
      console.log('In guard, canActivate() called');
      var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      var key = localStorage.getItem('key');
      var decodedtoken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
      console.log(decodedtoken);
      var tokenExpired:boolean = this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(JSON.stringify(token));
      console.log("tokenExpired was:" + tokenExpired);
      if (key=='ACCEPTED'&&!tokenExpired)
        return true; 
      else{
        this.router.navigate(['/events']);
        return false;
      }

  }
```

I'm expecting to get the id 4 logged in the console when I'm logged in with a non-expired token, as well as it displaying the right event in this case.
Currently it shows "0" as output.

Comment: Do you have the ID in token? You need to send ID with the token and then pass it in the `this.router.navigate(['/events']);`

Comment: @MaihanNijat That's the false route meaning it just redirects to the 'main page'. It's the true route that is the issue. The ID is pulled from my paramMap and it works as long as I have no guard on.

Comment: can you recreate this problem in stackblitz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two same routes in your routing configuration:

```
..
  {path: 'events/4', component: EventDetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailsComponent},
..
```

First route with `4` does not have `id` param. So when you open this route (`<base_href>/events/4`) you will get default value for number - `0`

So just replace `4` with `:id` and remove second route.

**UPDATE**

To implement guard only for `id === 4`, change your `canActivate` method a little bit:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

   const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');

   if(id !== 4)
    return true;

    ......
}
```

Comment: So, if I wanted just this one path; 4, to have the guard; how would I need to refactor my method of getting the ID?